# How to get parent id by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

```
<li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-52"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/">Trading Accounts</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/demo-account/">Get DEMO Account</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-44 current_page_item menu-item-54"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/live-account/">Get LIVE Account</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/deposit-and-withdrawal/">Deposit and Withdrawal</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

<script>
   $('.menu-item ul.sub-menu li').click(function(){
        var main_id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
</script>
```

i want to get this id 'menu-item-52' by click menu-item-55

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#menu-item-55').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id')
  console.log(id)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-52"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/">Trading Accounts</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/demo-account/">Get DEMO Account</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-44 current_page_item menu-item-54"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/live-account/">Get LIVE Account</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/deposit-and-withdrawal/">Deposit and Withdrawal</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Use `closest()` then add `li` to get the parent li

Comment: this will log clicked elements id as the element itself is li. and `.closest()` considers self element and its parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
$('.menu-item ul.sub-menu li').click(function(){
     var main_id = $(this).parent('ul').closest("li").attr("id");
     alert(main_id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-52"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/">Trading Accounts</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/demo-account/">Get DEMO Account</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-44 current_page_item menu-item-54"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/live-account/">Get LIVE Account</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="https://fxem.com/trading-accounts/deposit-and-withdrawal/">Deposit and Withdrawal</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using follwing jQuery Code:

```
$("#menu-item-55").closest('ul').parent().attr('id');
```

Checkout the fiddle link : [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/gtuLsvea/)

Hope it helps you :)